# How to make outset/inset stroke in inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, interface-design

I am trying to create SVG GUI item. Something like this:

[image: image description]

It has two inset borders. I don't even know how to force rectangle to have an inset border. How do I do that?

Comment: Haha, so I just figured it out and before I saved, inkscape crashed. Viva the free software.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to use gradients. By placing two gradient stops at the same location, you achieve the sharp switch:

[image: image description]

This is the result:

[image: image description]

Nest step is to turn the gradient ton 45°. I simply zoom in to put the gradient begin and and as close to the corner as possible:

[image: image description]

And here's the result, nice simple inset border:

[image: image description]